# How does Set ensure equatability in Swift?

Tags: swift, set, hashable

I'm reading [Set](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set)

> You use a set instead of an array when you need to test efficiently for membership and you aren’t concerned with the order of the elements in the collection, or when you need to ensure that each element appears only once in a collection.

Basically `Set` ensures uniqueness, it has some methods and relies on `Hashable`

> Use the contains(_:) method to test whether a set contains a specific element.
>
> Use the subtracting(_:) method to create a new set with the elements of a set that are not also in another set or sequence

But 2 different objects can have the same `hashValue`, like in this post [Swift Hashable](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-hashable/)

> Do not assume that two instances of a type with the same hash value are equal. Depending on how we compute the hash value we can get collisions where two different instances share the same hash value. The Hashable protocol only needs the reverse - two equal instances have the same hash value.

So what if 2 objects have the same `hashValue`, and `Set` only saves 1, then we have the problem?

Comment: The documentation nowhere states that only items with different hashValue are saved.

Comment: "So what if 2 objects have the same hashValue, and Set only saves 1, then we have the problem?"

No. Set will store 2 objects. This situation is called a hash collision and Set will handle that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An object that conforms to `Hashable` must also be `Equatable`.  `Set` uses `==` to test for equality, it doesn't depend only on the `hashValue`.

From Apple's documentation on [Hashable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable):

> **Conforming to the Hashable Protocol**
>  To use your own custom type in a
>   set or as the key type of a dictionary, add Hashable conformance to
>   your type by providing a hashValue property. The Hashable protocol
>   inherits from the Equatable protocol, so you must also add an equal-to
>   operator (==) function for your custom type.

The documentation goes on to say:

> Set and dictionary performance depends on hash values that minimize
>   collisions for their associated element and key types, respectively.

So, the `hashValue` is just used a first test for uniqueness; if the `hashValue`s match then `Set` will use the more computationally expensive `==` to test for uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the fact that Set uses `static func ==` to compare elements it can be done this way

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func subtracting(array: [Element]) -> [Element] {
        
        let hash1 = array.map({ $0.hashValue })
        let hash2 = self.map({ $0.hashValue })

        let resultSet = Set(hash2).subtracting(Set(hash1))

        let items = resultSet.compactMap({ item in self.first(where: { $0.hashValue == item }) })
        
        return items
    }
}

struct User: Hashable {
    var name: String
    var id: Int
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(name)
    }
}

let array1 = [User(name: "Bob", id: 1), User(name: "John", id: 2)]
let array2 = [User(name: "Bob", id: 1), User(name: "John", id: 2), User(name: "Bob", id: 2), User(name: "Marc", id: 6), User(name: "Brian", id: 7)]

let users = array2.subtracting(array: array1)

[User(name: "Brian", id: 7), User(name: "Marc", id: 6)]
```